# DNS A Records with 1and1 and Heroku

Tags: heroku, dns

I have a domain name registered through 1and1.com that I'd like to point to my Heroku app (mydomain.com and www.mydomain.com).
Heroku's instructions (http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains) say:

> Root domains (mydomain.com) must use A records To setup your root domain, add separate A records for each of the following addresses using your DNS management tool:
>   75.101.163.44,
>   75.101.145.87,
>   174.129.212.2

However 1and1 only allows one A record IP.

Is it sufficient to pick one of Heroku's three IPs, or is there a different way that I should set this up?

Thanks

Comment: I've seen plenty of other hosts that only permit 1 A record to 1 IP - don't know why they limit it (it's usually labelled ADVANCED control panel!) since it's perfectly valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get away with picking up one of the IPs, however the 3 IPs exist for redundancy & load balancing. So you'll miss out on that. For example if the one IP you pick is down, you'll lose access.

BTW, I don't know why 1and1 only allows you to setup one A records. It should be possible to add multiple A records, maybe the option is hidden somewhere. You should try contacting them to resolve this.

If not, see if this setup works:

```
yourdomain.com CNAME foo.yourdomain.com.
foo.yourdomain.com. A 75.101.163.44
foo.yourdomain.com. A 75.101.145.87
foo.yourdomain.com. A 174.129.212.2
```

Comment: I picked one IP and it has been working well.  But they definitely only allow on A record.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work anymore with the new Heroku routing requirements ? At least, I can't make it work anymore on a new application.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the easy way to do it now is with Point DNS. They have a free developer plan: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pointdns

Enter the Point DNS servers into the 1and1 Domain Managment page.